# Appending a form with select option fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to append a table with an additional row. It appends correctly except for the select option. My append jquery is:

```
$("#add_item").click(function(){
        $( "#itemlist" ).append( "\
            <tr id='add_item'>\
                <td class='add_item_strip'></td>\
                <td><input type='checkbox' value='1'/></td>\
                <td><input placeholder='Qty' class='qty' type='text'/></td>\
                <td>\
                    <select class='form-control type'/>\
                        <option value='service'>Service</option>\
                        <option value='hours'>Hours</option>\
                        <option value='days'>Days</option>\
                        <option value='product'>Product</option>\
                    </select>\
                </td>\
                <td><input placeholder='Name' class='name' type='text'/></td>\
                <td><input placeholder='Description' class='description'/></td>\
                <td><input placeholder='Price' type='text' class='price'/></td>\
                <th><input type='checkbox' value='7'/></th>\
                <td></td>\
                <td><input placeholder='Total' class='subtotal' type='text'/></td>\
            </tr>\
            <tr class='edit_table_space'>\
            </tr>\
        " );
    });
```

The html within my browser inspector is showing the options out of the select tag like this:

```
<select class="form-control type"></select>

<option value="service"></option>

<option value="hours"></option>

<option value="days"></option>

<option value="product"></option>
```

any idea why?

Comment: <select class='form-control type'/>\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are closing the `<select>` tag prematurely:

```
<select class='form-control type'/>
---------------------------------^
```

A `/>` closes the tag immediately. Try this:

```
...
<select class='form-control type'>\
    <option value='service'>Service</option>\
    <option value='hours'>Hours</option>\
    <option value='days'>Days</option>\
    <option value='product'>Product</option>\
</select>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the '/' at the end of the opening "SELECT" tag.

Also, please consider that appending this much text inline just might make future code management a pain. Try leaning on a templating system like handlebars.js